# 128x64 OLED Display Issue

Tags: gpio, python, i2c, display, output

I have a cheap display I got from eBay connected to a Raspberry Pi B+. It has 4 pins (vcc, gnd, scl, sda). I followed the adafruit tutorial [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_SSD1306/blob/master/README.md) but after setup, when I run a python example (any of the examples included with it), the one present is shapes.py), this is what my Display shows:

[image]

The output is very distorted, except the top bit of the display.

I have no clue what else to try. I made sure to edit the example.py file to use the 128x64 instead of the 128x32 but no luck. I have seen others with this issue but no solution that I found.

UPDATE: After looking at the original listing, it is a SSD1106, not a SSD1306. I believe this is my issue.

Comment: The Adafruit page says: "Designed specifically to work with the Adafruit SSD1306-based OLED displays" You don't have an Adafruit display.  Are you SSD1306-based? (You wrote SSD1603.)

Comment: Oops, yes, my mistake. Its a SSD1306

Comment: Any chance you swapped SCL and SDA in the wiring? Do you have any external pull-ups on the SDA and SCL lines?

Comment: @Brick I tried swapping my SCL and SDA wires and it makes the python example not run due to it not being connected, so that wasnt it. I do not have any pullups on the wires to any pins either.

Comment: You might need pull-ups. (The Adafruit boards have some power management components.) You also need to make sure that you have the right i2c address.  That's hard-coded in the python, and may or may not have the right value for your hardware. (Running out of ideas though, other than that I'm not sure this is promised to work if you don't have the Adafruit board - I haven't looked at the schematic in detail but they may some other components on there that their code assumes to be in place.)

Comment: The address of my i2c display is 3c, which is the default in the python script it appears.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I was using the wrong Library. The device I have is a SH1106, not a SSD1306. When using the proper library ([Like this one](https://pypi.org/project/luma.oled/)) It works fine.